# Gradle + Scala + Intellij "Create separate module per source set"

Tags: scala, gradle, intellij-idea

Gradle version: 4.2.2.
Intellij version: 2019.1.1.

I am trying to setup a Scala/Gradle project in Intellij (via importing the build.gradle) using the "Create separate module per source set" option enabled.

Whenever I enable this option, Intellij doesn't identify that its a Scala project so I can't create Scala files. Without this option checked - it works perfectly.

My file structure:

```
/service1/api/scala
/service1/main/scala
/service2/api/scala
/service2/main/scala
/build.gradle
/settings.gradle
```

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "idea"

subprojects {
  apply plugin: "scala"

  configurations {
    api
    apiCompile.extendsFrom(compile)
  }

  sourceSets {
    api {
      scala.srcDirs = ["api/scala"]
    }
    main {
      scala.srcDirs = ["main/scala"]
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    zinc ...  // some zinc dependencies - not important
    compile files("D:\\scala-library-2.12.6.jar")
  }
}
```